# What does “Go back on the loaf” mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

There is a video game titled “The Suffering”. This game stars a character named Torque, who has been sent to Abbott State Penitentiary on Carnate Island off the coast of Maryland. Torque has been put on death row for (seemingly) murdering his ex-wife and two sons. The truth behind their deaths is…complicated.

Shortly after Torque is put in a cell, the other inmates begin talking about him. Some of them believe Torque committed the crimes, while others don’t think so. It leads to an argument so loud and hostile that a correction officer has to break it up through a loudspeaker as follows.

> **Correction Officer**: Quiet down in there! Some of you wanna `go back on the loaf`? [Beat] I didn’t think so.

I have racked my brains trying to figure out what “go back on the loaf” means. Is it referring to food? Is it referring to some sort of punishment? It could be prison slang for all I know.

If there is anyone here who can explain to me what the phrase means, I will be very happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a prisoner in many US jails is punished by being "put on the loaf", he or she is, for a period, deprived of variety at meal times, and is served a type of meat loaf. The practice has been legally challenged by prisoners who allege that it is "cruel and unusual punishment", which is forbidden by the Eighth Amendment to the US Constitution.

> On Christmas Day, the inmates at Santa Cruz County Jail will get a
> welcome respite from their regularly scheduled, nutritious but mostly
> unexciting high school cafeteria-style meals — glazed ham with sweet
> potatoes and ice cream for dessert.
>
> If an inmate has been behaving poorly, however, while all his
> incarcerated compatriots dine on one of the few special meals of the
> year, he will instead be forced to feast on “the loaf.”
>
> Otherwise known as the disciplinary diet loaf, prison loaf and
> management loaf, when all else fails in disciplining an inmate — be it
> loss of visits, free time or other privileges — the deputies turn to
> this bland log of meat and vegetables to get the disruptive inmate to
> follow the rules.

[News story](https://www.mercurynews.com/2010/12/17/when-santa-cruz-county-inmates-act-out-the-loaf-is-served/)

Comment: Ah, meat loaf instead of bread and water. This makes more sense. At least in reality.

Comment: I quite like meat loaf, but I imagine that having it for every meal might begin to pall.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sir, thank you very much for your answer! This question had been on my mind for quite some time. Now I feel relieved.

Comment: Also, I like meat loaf myself, but like you said, I wouldn't want to eat it every time!